# Conditionally add key/value pairs of two separate objects (one in array within initial state) for array method inside of useState() hook

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, use-state

Right now, this doesn't work.

```
const item = {name: "mike", apples: 20}

const [list, setList] = useState([{name: "peter", apples: 30}, {name: "mike", apples: 39}])

setList(list.map(entry => entry.name == item.name ? entry.apples = item.apples+entry.apples : entry = entry))
```

I am able to get it working with the code below. I know it's not clean and that's why I'm trying to get the top code working the **react way**: using es6 within useState hook.

```
  let newList = [...list]
  let changed = false
  newList.map(entry => {
    if(entry.name == item.name) {
      entry.apples = item.apples+entry.apples
    }
  if(changed) {
    setList(newList)
  }
```

Edit: I've also tried functional update on the state like below

```
setList(list => list.map(entry => entry.name == item.name ? entry.apples = item.apples+entry.apples : entry = entry))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the right way:

```
setList((previousList) =>
  previousList.map((entry) =>
    entry.name == item.name
      ? { ...entry, apples: entry.apples + item.apples }
      : entry
  )
);
```

---

```
entry.name == item.name ? entry.apples = item.apples+entry.apples
```

will not work because `entry.apples = item.apples+entry.apples` returns apples, but each element of the array should remain an object and you should also make sure that the state is not mutated (`entry.apples = ...` is bad because `entry` is mutated)

Comment: This solved it! Thank you!!!
I totally derped on what was being returned and how I should've used a spread operator to change the object inside the conditional ternary.